# How do we run programs which are bigger than RAM itself

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems

I know that whenever click on .exe, it will be moved into RAM so cpu can execute machine code line by line. But what if .exe is bigger than RAM?

for eg: I play games which take up more space than my RAM. My RAM is 8gb, but i can still play them.
How's that possible

Comment: The games usually don't have gigabytes of code but gigabytes of textures, audio and 3d models etc. These are only loaded into RAM when needed. If you really had a piece of code longer than your RAM the operating systems memory [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging) will solve this. Basically the operating system loads only the code that is currently needed, and stores the rest on your hard drive in an area called "swap".

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of clarification I'll answer this :

> I play games which take up more space than my RAM. My RAM is 8gb, but i can still play them. How's that possible

Games are typically made up of large amounts of data and less code.  Quite a lot of the data will typically be textures and other data related to graphics.  It's becoming common for games to have e.g. 50+ GB of mostly data.  I have an install of the game Fallout 4 (with some mods) which is about 36 GB in size on the disk however only about 1 GB is executable code.

The computer does not usually need all that data at the same time.  When it does it fetches just the data it needs.  It will make room by removing (from memory) data it does not think it will need.  This is complicated by the common scenario of a CPU with RAM and a GPU with it's own graphics memory on the graphics card.  The memory on the GPU (which is specifically designed for GPU operations) will then be the limiting resource not the RAM.  There's also a lot of management going on behind the scenes.  The CPU/OS will be caching files and parts of files it thinks it needs and managing that caching.  The GPU/graphics engine will be also managing the GPU's use of memory particularly textures.

If you don't have enough RAM to load the executable and required library files then the game is unlikely to even launch.  In principle an executable can run using virtual memory but in practice the executable will have to at least fit in available free physical memory or the OS is unlikely to even launch it.  Where virtual memory comes into play is when it needs to swap between executable code or data which is paged in and paged out.  Essentially the OS makes an educated guess as to what it expects to need and what it can let go to free up space.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer's operating system uses [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), which addresses this problem by loading only part of the .exe in memory at any one time, based on what parts are currently needed.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory.

That said, in practice, .exe files are rarely larger than the amount of RAM.  When you say that games take up more than 8 GB, it's more likely that this size is due to the data that they load.  Some programs are written to only load data that they need at any time, and unload it when it is unneeded, so that they don't exceed the amount of RAM you have.  If that fails, or if for whatever reason a program loads/uses more data than you have RAM for, memory paging is used to keep in RAM what is currently being used and temporarily store the rest on disk.